# Create a image-mask with p5js

Tags: javascript, image, mask, p5.js

Im trying to figure out if its possible to have a blank canvas and then place a image and have it masked by a random shape? That or use a png as mask.

Thank you

M

Answer (score 0):

Yup it is possible and quite trivial with the [`mask()`](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5.Image/mask) function on the `p5.Image` class (it's too bad they don't list this class member functions on the main page of the [reference](https://p5js.org/reference/) but if you use the search box you'll find these types of things).

Given the image:

[image: arbitrary jpg]

And the mask PNG:

[image: mask with alpha channel]

You can render the masked image like so:

```js
let img;
let mask;

function preload() {
  img = loadImage('https://www.paulwheeler.us/files/windows-95-desktop-background.jpg');
  mask = loadImage('https://www.paulwheeler.us/files/Vase-Illusion.png');
}

function setup() {
  createCanvas(windowWidth, windowHeight);
  
  img.mask(mask);
  
  noLoop();
}

function draw() {
  image(img, 0, 0, height * (img.width / img.height), height)
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.4.0/p5.js"></script>
```